# How to style individual pages in Angular NativeScript?

Tags: nativescript, angular2-nativescript

I'm building a NativeScript app with Angular2 and the  and I want to style each Page differently with a unique background image, etc. I cannot target the "Page" element in the individual component.css files, but I can target Page in the master `app.css` file. The problem is that sets the style for every single page. I want them to be unique.

The hack I have figured out now is to use `this.page.setInlineStyle('background-color: purple;');` inside the `ngOnInit()` function in each component.

Is there a way to simply target the pages from individual routes from the `app.css` file?

Comment: You can add individual css files for each page where you can add their unique styles.

Comment: @HardikVaghani the problem is that the Page element cannot be targeted from the individual component CSS files. It is higher in the DOM tree.

Comment: Have you tried styling your root layout for each page? Giving, say, your StackLayout a class of "page" and, then having the css style it to take up the whole page and then define the background for it as @HardikVaghani suggests?

Comment: Just FYI there is not DOM in NativeScript, you mean the UI tree

Comment: @VladimirAmiorkov yes, "UI Tree" is the word I'm looking for.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My preferred approach is to get a reference to the `<Page>` in an `ngOnInit()` handler, and to apply a CSS class name that I can use as a styling hook in my `app.css` file. So for example:

```
// my-page.component.ts
import { Component, OnInit } from "@angular/core";
import { Page } from "ui/page";

@Component({ ... })
export class MyPage implements OnInit {
  constructor(private page: Page) {}
  ngOnInit() {
    this.page.className = "my-page";
  }
}

/* app.css */
.my-page {
  background-color: yellow;
}
```

I do this in the NativeScript Groceries sample if you’re looking for a fully-functional solution. See https://github.com/NativeScript/sample-Groceries/blob/9eb6fea66e3912878815b86aa5ce7b812e22eac5/app/groceries/groceries.component.ts#L36 and https://github.com/NativeScript/sample-Groceries/blob/9eb6fea66e3912878815b86aa5ce7b812e22eac5/app/app.css#L7-L12.

Answer (score 1):

It's working for me (in NativeScript), I usually do like that in Angular for web:

```
/deep/ Page {
  background: #whatever;
}
```